# I deleted erased all content from my emulator device in iOS, after this, i cant insert or read in my sqlite db

Tags: ios, swift, database, sqlite, mobile

I erased my device content and settings and since that i cant insert nothing into my sqlite db.
My query to create the table runs and the tables are created ( i can see in the db browser) but my methos to insert and read just stoped working.

What can i do ?

I already tried to create antoher db with another name ans doesnt work.

```
enter cclass DBHelper {
init()
{
    db = openDatabase()
    createTable()
}

let dbPath: String = "prescriptionDB.sqlite"
var db:OpaquePointer?

func createTable() {
    let createTableString = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prescriptions(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT ,name TEXT ,timeToTime TEXT ,firstTime TEXT);"
    var createTableStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, createTableString, -1, &createTableStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK
    {
        if sqlite3_step(createTableStatement) == SQLITE_DONE
        {
            print("prescriptions table created.")
        } else {
            print("prescriptions table could not be created.")
        }
    } else {
        print("CREATE TABLE statement could not be prepared.")
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(createTableStatement)
}


func insert(name: String, timeToTime: String, firstTime: String) {
    let insertStatementString = "INSERT INTO prescriptions (name, timeToTime, firstTime) VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
    var insertStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
  
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStatementString, -1, &insertStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 1, (name as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 2, (timeToTime as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(insertStatement, 3, (firstTime as NSString).utf8String, -1, nil)
        
        if sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Successfully inserted row.")
        } else {
            print("Could not insert row.")
        }
    } else {
        print("INSERT statement could not be prepared.")
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
}

func openDatabase() -> OpaquePointer? {
    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent(dbPath)
    var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
    if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK
    {
        print("error opening database")
        return nil
    }
    else
    {
        print("Successfully opened connection to database at \(dbPath)")
        return db
    }
}

func read() -> [Prescription] {
    let queryStatementString = "SELECT * FROM prescriptions;"
    var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    var psns : [Prescription] = []
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStatementString, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {
            let id = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0)
            let name = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 1)))
            let timeToTime = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 2)))
            let firstTime = String(describing: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 3)))
            psns.append(Prescription(name: name, timeToTime: timeToTime, id: Int(id), firstTime: firstTime))
            print("Query Result:")
            print("\(id) | \(name) | \(timeToTime) | \(firstTime)")
        }
    } else {
        print("SELECT statement could not be prepared")
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
    return psns
}ode here
```

Comment: what is the result code returned by ```sqlite3_step(insertStatement)``` ?

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake. The issues is beacuse my insert method war not beeing called in this version, so, when i tried to read from db, there is no rows, so, it returns false

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).